# Laravel getting distinct value from MySQL column not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to get distinct values in a dropdown from one column, I tried these queries in my controller, but I am getting an empty result.

**Controller Query 1 Tried**

```php
public function create()
{
    $categories = Category::all();
    $status = Category::all()->groupby('SM')->get();

    return view('admin.categories.create', compact('categories', 'status'));
}
```

**Query 2**

```php
$status = Category::distinct()->get(['SM']);
```

**View**

```
<label>Distinct</label>
<select  name="dropdown">
    <option value="{{$status}}"></option>
</select>
{{$status}}
```

I am trying to get the distinct value of a column in a dropdown.

Comment: To start try to put something inside the option tag, i.e.; `<option value="{{$status}}">Hello World</option>`

Comment: only Hello world in drop down.

Comment: Better than nothing. Now try this: `@foreach ($status as $stat) <option value="{{$stat}}">{{$stat}}</option> @endforeach`

Comment: @dparoli the OP is getting nothing in `dd($status)`

Comment: Sorry but Stackoverflow is not a code review service, IMHO this code has some issues and we can only try to guess. The OP did not provide yet a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: i will run loop but {{$status}} should return everything but it's empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering `SM` your column name. In Eloquent you can try something like below:

```
$status = Category::select('SM')->distinct()->get();
```

or using pluck:

```
$status = Category::distinct('SM')->pluck('SM');
```

Also you should add some value inside option tag like:

```
<option value="{{ $status }}"> {{ $status }}</option>
```

Comment: it returned empty result, nothing is on view.

Comment: `dd($status)` and see what it returns?

Comment: @iscpreee it means you're getting empty record! Are you sure your table has data?

Comment: yes column has data, i tried with different columns but still same.

Comment: your query is returning only { 2 values, single and married} while there are more values in column like, sing,mar etc. why it is so?

Comment: Which code you have added? and may be single and married is the only distinct values in your column or is there any other also?

Comment: these are values{ sing,marr,single,married,lang} 
your both queries returning same result, only single and married.

Comment: if i run your query on id coloumn(range 1-25) it returns these values 10 18 19 20 21 22 23 24

Comment: @iscpreee do you have teamviewer installed? Let's check it in your PC and move to chat!

Comment: really sorry for bothering you, i think i soft deleted/trashed those values which are in column but query is not going through those.

Comment: problem is solved, jazak ALLAH. you are doing great job, keep it up.

Comment: @iscpreee no worries. Glad to know that it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

If you do `Category:all()->groupBy()->get()` you are applied to your collection helpers of you `select * from categories` , you don't make a MySQL Query.

If you wanna applied to MySQL Query, you need to do

```
Category::select('SM')->groupBy('SM')->get();
```

or

```
Category::select('SM')->distinct()->get();
```

Comment: i pasted your query but nothing is returned in view.

Comment: and just Category::distinct()->get() ?

Comment: @iscpreee So what was the issue that you were getting empty status?

Comment: @Iftikharuddin if you check my route i was on edit page, if you check my code i was coding on create controller.

Comment: @iscpreee I mentioned that in my comment however glad to know that your problem is solved!